# Javascript: Implement precise clock

Tags: javascript, angular, event-loop

I am implementing a live clock in front-end of a large application. For that I have came up with following approach -

JavaScript

```
var span = document.getElementById('span');

function time() {
  var d = new Date();
  var s = d.getSeconds();
  var m = d.getMinutes();
  var h = d.getHours();
  span.textContent = h + ":" + m + ":" + s;
}

setInterval(time, 1000);
```

HTML

```
<span id="span"></span>
```

This approach works perfectly fine in isolation, but when this code is integrated in the application which is having several events and function calls, the clock starts lagging by few minutes after say couple of hours until the page is refreshed.

I think this delay is because of `setInterval` being a web (browser) API and is handled asynchronously it may not execute exactly after 1 second as written in the code every time, if the call stack is not empty after 1 second from time being `setInterval` is registered due to other function calls/ events present in the call stack of event loop.

So if the page is not refreshed for long time the delay continues to grow. Also the application is written in Angular which is a Single Page application where the page never reloads on navigation because of routing until the page is forcefully refreshed.

So how to build a precise clock in JavaScript which will never delay when integrated in a large application?

**Update**: Thanks everyone for the response. I think some of you are right, I may be missing some of the details. Actually I was implementing this few days back at work, but have to left this due to some reason and lost track of it. But there was some delay issue for sure working with `Date` and `Timers`. Suddenly now this came to my mind and thought asking it here. Extremely sorry for not providing concrete details.

Still I will try to recollect the details and update the question accordingly if possible.

Comment: We need to se the rest of the code really

Comment: Have you tried it with `RxJS` and `data-binding`?

Answer (score 2):

> the clock starts lagging by few minutes after say couple of hours until the page is refreshed.

Thats impossible with the code you've shown, `new Date` should return the correct time, no matter how often you reflect its value to the page.

> So if the page is not refreshed for long time the delay continues to grow.

Most browsers today will adjust the timers slightly, so that they are quite accurate on average (e.g. if one timer gets called to late by 1ms, the next will be called 1ms earlier), therefore you can only cause a drift over a longer time if you will leave the page, which will pause the timer. That still shouldn't affect `new Date` though.

Have a look at the [Chromium source](https://codereview.chromium.org/1373503002)

Comment: Even if the time does get "off track" due to losing focus, since the interval is calling `new Date` every time it runs, it will not be compounding onto an existing time, but rather grabbing a *new* time every interval (in this case 1 second). So if it does get off track, it should call a completely independent time within 1 second that "fixes" itself. Jonas is right that there shouldn't be any issues here.

Comment: It's possible, but only if the code doesn't ever run again to update the clock.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder yes, but background timers get throttled to seconds, not minutes.

Comment: @JonasWilms - I don't think that's necessarily true. Chrome is **really** aggressive about it. But it doesn't matter. Fundamentally, the OP's reported symptom doesn't really match the presented code, so we're just taking our best stabs at it. :-)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder jup. Out of curiosity: What was the meaning of the british (?) flag in your profile?

Comment: @JonasWilms - It was the New Zealand flag, in honor of those injured and killed in the mosque shooting.

Comment: @JonasWilms - Don't be, you weren't the only one. With it being an overlay, and with the NZ flag having the union jack in the upper left-hand corner... :-) The rest of the flag got a bit lost in the mix.

Answer (score 1):

Timers in web browsers get dialled back when the page doesn't have focus. You can't change or prevent that. You're *already* doing the primary thing that's important: Using the *current* time to update the clock, so that even if your `time` function isn't called for three seconds, when it runs it updates with the then-current time, skipping over the intermediate values. (You often see people assuming the timer will run at exactly 1000ms intervals and just adding to the seconds value rather than using the current time, which is incorrect.)

If I were doing this, I'd probably decrease the interval (run the callback more often) and use a chained series of `setTimeout` rather than a single `setInterval`, not least because different browsers have historically handled `setInterval` in different ways.

So for instance:

```
function time() {
  var d = new Date();
  var s = d.getSeconds();
  var m = d.getMinutes();
  var h = d.getHours();
  span.textContent = h + ":" + m + ":" + s;
  setTimeout(time, 250);
}

time();
```

But if the page is inactive, the clock *will* get out of date, because the browser will either completely suspend timer execution or at least markedly dial it back. When the page becomes active again, though, hopefully it'll correct itself after no more than 250ms.

Comment: Also, if possible please take a look at web workers and idle timeout if your target browsers support it.

Comment: @ashish.gd - I don't think web workers will help here. Do you have some reference suggesting that a web worker's timers are not dialled back, or are dialled back less? And that the main window will process `message` events from the worker when the page is inactive?

Comment: But isn't setInterval the better choice due to drift correction? https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/21822 or does that also apply to recurring timers?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder you are right, I do not have strong reference to suggest web workers will process even when the page is inactive. It was based on my understanding, that they will not rely on the main thread and hence the call stack emptiness, which in turn might give some what close to real setTimeout behaviour.

Comment: @JonasWilms - With the short interval, it doesn't matter, and it's partially because different browsers do or don't do drift correction (and/or start the next interval from the beginning of the callback or the end) that I prefer `setTimeout`'s clearer semantics. (Note that Node.js's `setInterval` is very different from the one in browsers. And also very strange and non-intuitive.)